# Create standard price book programmatically

Tags: apex, api, salesforcedx-cli

I’ve created a scratch org, but it’s empty without a price book. I’d like to create it with script/code/CLI so it can be automated. Unless the price book is in place I can’t really add products w price.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Apex:

In Apex, you can create a Price Book ([`Pricebook2`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_pricebook2.htm)) and a Product ([`Product2`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_product2.htm)) and relate the two records with a Price Book Entry ([`PricebookEntry`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_pricebookentry.htm)) using the following method:

```
// Create a Pricebook

Pricebook2 priceBook = new Pricebook2(
    Name = 'Example Price Book',
    Description = 'This is the Price Book description.',
    IsActive = true
);

insert priceBook;

// Create a Product

Product2 product = new Product2(
    Name = 'Example Product',
    Description = 'This is the Product description.',
    ProductCode = 'EX1234',
    StockKeepingUnit = 'EX5678',
    Family = 'Example Product Family',
    QuantityUnitOfMeasure = 'inches',
    DisplayUrl = 'https://www.example.com/',
    ExternalId = 'ID #1234',
    ExternalDataSourceId = '0XCXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    IsActive = true
);

insert product;

// Get the Standard Price Book ID

Pricebook2 standardPriceBook = [
    SELECT Id
      FROM Pricebook2
     WHERE isStandard = true
     LIMIT 1
];

// Insert the Product in the Standard Price Book (if necessary)

PricebookEntry standardPriceBookEntry = new PricebookEntry(
    Pricebook2Id = standardPriceBook.Id,
    Product2Id = product.Id,
    UnitPrice = 100.00,
    UseStandardPrice = false,
    IsActive = true
);

insert standardPriceBookEntry;

// Insert the Product in the New Price Book

PricebookEntry priceBookEntry = new PricebookEntry(
    Pricebook2Id = priceBook.Id,
    Product2Id = product.Id,
    UnitPrice = 100.00,
    UseStandardPrice = false,
    IsActive = true
);

insert priceBookEntry;
```

#### SFDX:

If you store the above Apex code in a file (*i.e. **example.apex***), in SFDX, you can run the [`apex:execute`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_apex.htm#cli_reference_execute) command to execute the code anonymously to create the Price Book in the org:

```
sfdx force:apex:execute --apexcodefile ~/example.apex
```